# How to transform Ruby hash to CSS rule?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a hash something like:

```
hash = {"body"=>{"background_color"=>"#d6e9c6"}, "control_label"=>{"font_family"=>"arial", "font_size"=>"12px"}}
```

How to transform it to such css rule?

```
body { 
  background-color: d6e9c6 
}

.control_label { 
  font-family: "Arial"; 
  font-size: "12px" 
}
```

Have done this so far, but stuck, any help would be great.

```
hash.map {|k,v| "#{k} #{v.keys.map(&:dasherize)}"}.join("\n")
```

Comment: The question as it is stated, has no correct answer. `body` and `control_label` are undistinguishable as hash keys, while you expect the former to become `body` and the latter become `.control_label`.

Comment: In addition to mudasobwa's comment, what rule removes `#`, and what are the rules for capitalizing?

Comment: Downvoted?? why?? the question has correct answer, everything except body has to be prepended with comma, eg. class in css

Comment: I did not downvote, but I can explain, why. The very first comment states that your question is incomplete, it”s just illegal so that it has no correct answer. Despite that you did not modify the question to conform SO rules. Hence you were punished. As easy as that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it in the page, like so.

```
<% hash.each do |rule,styles| %>
  <%= rule %> {
    <% styles.each do |k,v| %>
      <%= k %>: <% v.inspect %>;
    <% end %>
  }
<% end %>
```

You could have this as a partial which takes `hash` as a local variable, or you could make a helper for it:

```
def hash_to_css(hash)
  lines = []
  hash.each do |rule,styles|
    lines << "#{rule} {"
    styles.each do |k,v|
      lines << "  #{k}: #{v.inspect};"
    end
    lines << "}"
  end
  lines.join("\n")
end
```

Now on your page you can just say

```
<%= hash_to_css(@my_css_hash) %>
```

EDIT:  as @mudosowba points out in a comment, in order for this to work, the "input" information needs to be correct in the first place.  ie, you would need to have `".control_label"` as a hash key rather than `"control_label"`.

Comment: There is no operating systems save for unix, yes. Besides that your code simply won’t produce a desired output.

Comment: I don't understand your point about operating systems...  as for my code, i think it will work given the correct input, eg ".control_label" rather than "control_label".  I think the questioner just got the input wrong in his question.

Comment: thanks @MaxWilliams almost got it working, regarding input, it's control_label but in css it should be applied for class eg. .control_label

Comment: You need to change the input then.  It's not reasonable to expect the code to "know" whether the hash key refers to a type of element (no dot) or a class (with a dot).

Comment: Having said that, you *could* have the method contain an array of all known element types, and insert a dot if the key isn't in the array.  However, this is pretty horrible.  I would put the expectation on the caller of the method to get the input right in the first place.

Comment: Regarding OS: `.join("\n")` is just lame, it should be `join($/)`.

Comment: Ah, i see.  Yes, it's recommended to use the OS-specific line break when rendering html.  I don't think using \n will make it break in any browsers though.

Comment: Using `\n` would not break any browser. Whether you care about browsers only, just stick to simple space.

Answer (score 0):

```
TAGS=['body']
hash.map do |k, v| 
  (TAGS.include?(k) ? k.to_s : ".#{k}") + 
    " {" + 
      v.map { |k, v| "#{k.tr('_','-')}: \"#{v}\";" }.join($/) + 
    "}"
end.join($/)
```

First of all, you are to specify what is to be treated as tags, and what is to be prepended with dot, like for classes. This approach is easily extendable to `id`s (`#blah`). `TAGS` constant is used to determine whether we should prepend dot for css rule.

Then we just map hash keys to css rules, mapping internal hashes to css directives. There in directives, underscores are substituted to dashes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What about  little explanation?

Comment: Updated. I just dropped it here for future visitors, since a phpish approach above looks weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick monkey patch for `Hash` (you can put that in an Rails initializer):

```
module ToCss
  def to_css
    select { |_, t| t }.keys.join(" ")
  end
end

Hash.include(ToCss)
```

You can then use it this way:

```
{ 'class1' => condition1, 'class2' => condition2 }.to_css
# Will return "class1 class2" if both condition1 and condition2 are truthy
# Will return "class1" if only condition1 is truthy
# Will return "" if both conditions are falsy
```